# Scrolling just by very little

Tags: android

I have a problem in Android studio. I need to make this layout to scroll, however, it is scrolling by very little.

What could be the problem?

Have tried several of solutions till now, but nothing yet works.

using setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) doesn't work, since i am tackling older API's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <one.triangle.me.element.TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/element_1"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="•"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/multi_item_selected"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/whatever"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why android:layout_height="35dp" in ScrollView

Comment: "using setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) doesn't work, since i am tackling older API's" - `NestedScrollView` is part of the support library, so it should be compatible with older devices.

Comment: what should be best thing to write instead?

Comment: android:layout_height="match_parent"
set height as match parent instead of static height.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height` from ScrollView, as their childs have greater height than parent view. So either make it `wrap_content` or `match_parent`.

Comment: Your content is very less, either extend height of ScrollBar to test and also use fillViewPort property of ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Update your xml code like below :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Tried this before, still the same moving by very little